# How do I return the pkgInfo object from this arrow function?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I installed an npm library reiko parser and it shows the pkgInfo object using console log. I changed the code to return this pkgInfo object but it returns undefined. I'm new to arrow functions so I'm quite lost how to get the pkgInfo object unless I declare a static variable and assign it the value of pkgInfo object which is bad practice?

```
function get_icon(serverFilePath) {
    const readerPkg = new PkgReader(serverFilePath, 'apk', { withIcon: true });
    return readerPkg.parse((err, pkgInfo) => {
        
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(pkgInfo); // works with console log but not return??
           return pkgInfo //undefined
        }
    });
   
}
```

EDIT: This is also the code that was given in the npm pg

```
const reader =

     new PkgReader(filePath, 'apk', { withIcon: true });
    reader.parse((err, pkgInfo) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log(pkgInfo); // pkgInfo.icon is encoded to base64
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

should just be `return pkgInfo` same as a normal function

Comment: No for some reason if I call return in the parse function itself it returns undefined.

Comment: what happens if you just do `return readerPkg.parse((err, pkgInfo) => {
        
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(pkgInfo); 
        }
    });`
Does that work?

Comment: It still returns undefined...and then it prints the pkgInfo to console.It seems like reader.parse is always called at the end of the function after the return is called